# How to open multiple chrome windows and force them to always be active?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to open multiple chrome windows using selenium, but I always faced an issue that when I opened too many (like 7 windows), some of them would go inactive causing the program to throw `NoSuchElementException`. I don't know if there is a problem with my RAM as it seems fine, also I am running on 16GB RAM, so I can't find a cause for windows to go inactive. I thought of a workaround but it is not very sufficient which is to open them in windowed mode and keep all of them. Is there any other solution like a setting in chrome or sth?

Edit: this PC is devoted for this task, so no other processes are interfering with the program